# MiKTeX 2.9 installation problem

Tags: miktex, installing

Whenever I am installing miktex 2.9 in my windows 7 32 bit system, getting a particular error. I have tried many times even disabled the antivirus. I had previous miktx 2.5. After uninstalling 2.5, I am facing this problem. 
The miktex 2.9 is working fine in other system.

[image: The error message is here.]

Comment: Welcome! Did you try running it as Admin?

Comment: What about Antivirus? Did you try it with disabled AV scanner?

Comment: You don't have the newest installer. According to miktex.org the version is basic-miktex-2.9.6236.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I found less issues if I "install just for you", ie local install. Watch your antivirus software as I had AVG once pull a MikTeX package that had me scratching my head. Use the latest basic installer and allow for auto downloading of missing packages. Also watch the repository you update from as an out of date repository can cause occasional problems. Considering the overall complexity, MikTeX is a remarkable tool.